# Flutter: How to make my dialog box scrollable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm just new in flutter and now I have a problem in my dialog box. The problem is that my dialog box is becoming overflowed because of texts. So, now I want to make it scrollable so that texts still can be viewed. I already put a "SingleChildScrollView" on it but still doesn't work Please help.

My code:

```
_viewingRequest(dynamic data) async {
return showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext,
    builder: (context) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: AlertDialog(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
          title: Center(child: Text("Information")),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
          content: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                    'Name of requestor: ${data['Name_ofUser']}'
                ),
                Text(
                  'Description:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '${data['Help_Description']}',
                ),
                Text(
                  'Type of help needed: ${data['Help_TypeNeeded']}',
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: new Text(
                      'Fund',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      saveIssue();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 70.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: new Text(
                        'Cancel',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
 }
```

My UI:

[Link for my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt7AO.png)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Change position of SingleChildScrollView to on top of Column works fine

```
return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
            title: Center(child: Text("Information")),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
            content: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                        'Name of requestor: }'
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Description:' * 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Help_Description',
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Type of help needed:Help_TypeNeeded',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyStatelessApp());
}

class MyStatelessApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dialog Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: StatelessWidgetDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class StatelessWidgetDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StatelessWidgetDemoState createState() => _StatelessWidgetDemoState();
}

class _StatelessWidgetDemoState extends State<StatelessWidgetDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Dialog Demo'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _showTestDialog();
                    },
                    child: Text('Show Test Dialog'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _showCupertinoDialog();
                    },
                    child: Text('Show Cupertino Dialog'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _showSimpleDialog();
                    },
                    child: Text('Show Simple Dialog'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }

  void _showTestDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        //context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
            title: Center(child: Text("Information")),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
            content: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                        'Name of requestor: }'
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Description:' * 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Help_Description',
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Type of help needed:Help_TypeNeeded',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: new Text(
                        'Fund',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        //saveIssue();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 70.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: new Text(
                          'Cancel',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void _showMaterialDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Material Dialog'),
            content: Text('This is the content of the material dialog'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _dismissDialog();
                  },
                  child: Text('Close')),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('HelloWorld!');
                  _dismissDialog();
                },
                child: Text('HelloWorld!'),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  _dismissDialog() {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void _showCupertinoDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Cupertino Dialog'),
            content: Text('This is the content of the cupertino dialog'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _dismissDialog();
                  },
                  child: Text('Close')),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('HelloWorld!');
                  _dismissDialog();
                },
                child: Text('HelloWorld!'),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void _showSimpleDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: Text('Chosse an Option'),
            children: <Widget>[
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  _dismissDialog();
                },
                child: const Text('Option 1'),
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  _dismissDialog();
                },
                child: const Text('Option 2'),
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  _dismissDialog();
                },
                child: const Text('Option 3'),
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  _dismissDialog();
                },
                child: const Text('Option 4'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I didnt upvote the answer, this was popping up when I clicked it.

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Thanks that worked.  If you use a listview then the dropdownbutton does not display selections after the setstate, even though the setstate fires.   SingleChildScrollView does not interfere with the dropdownbutton hydration.  Thanks

Comment: Setting hard coded height and width is not perfect solution because device orientation can be horizontal and vertical. If we are in vertical view then should use available full height instead of hard coded height. Its my view, just sharing, not saying wrong to your answer or marking wrong. Please don't mind. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16):

Just simply set the `scrollable` param of the `AlertDialog` to `true` to wrap both the `title` and `content` widgets in a scroll view, allowing all overflowed content to be visible while still showing the button bar.

```dart
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () => showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Reason'),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius:
              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
      scrollable: true,
      content: Text('Super long content here'),
      actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      actions: [
        OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: Text('I have done reading ✓'),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('View reason for visit'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

define the future dialog

```
 Future<bool>_loadForm(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Dialog(child: MyWidget(params));
    });
  }
```

from a card in a list view call dialog from an onPressed event

```
  onPressed: () => 
  _loadChecklistForm(context).then((values)=>{})
```

in myWidget in the build return a Dialog

```
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 List<Widget> formWidgetList = new List();

 formWidgetList.add(new Text('Hello world'));  

 return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:     Column(children:formWidgetList) ));
```